# How to use a preprocessor to separate parameters from function signatures in C++?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, auto-generate

I am using a C++preprocessor to batch generate function definitions, but there is an issue when passing parameters

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define FOR_EACH_FUNC(_) \
    _(int, add, int a, int b) \
    _(int, subtract, int a, int b)

#define FORWARD_FUNC(ret, func, ...) \
    ret func(__VA_ARGS__) { \
        impl->func(__VA_ARGS__); \        // error!
    } \

FOR_EACH_FUNC(FORWARD_FUNC)

int main()
{
    int r1 = add(1, 2);
    int r2 = subtract(1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

The result I want is

```cpp
int add(int a, int b) {
    impl->add(a, b);
}
```

But the current result is

```cpp
int add(int a, int b) {
    impl->add(int a, int b);
}
```

Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks

I tried using C++'s variable parameter template to solve it, but it was not successful

**Supplementary explanation:**

We have a library A that needs to be used by a third party, but it relies on many other libraries. In order to clean up the compilation dependencies of others, we have implemented an intermediate library B that calls the methods of A through `dlopen/dlsys` (library A and its dependencies will be built into our system).

The problem here is: to implement a function, we need to first implement it in A, then define it in B as well, then define the function pointer, find the corresponding function address, and implement a simple logic to forward the request to A. I want to simplify this process

Comment: would `int add(auto a,auto b)` be acceptable?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. The answer is no, I need to clearly define the type of each parameter, as I also need to use it to generate function declarations for third-party use

Comment: What you're trying to do? Sounds like an XY problem

Comment: the preprocessor is the obvious tool to preprocess code, but consider that there are much simpler way to generate this code. Eg a python script would need a 2-3 lines only, without the compilications you have now. I also think it would help if you explain the use case

Comment: Yes, Python is an alternative solution, but it will make building links more complex

Comment: "building links" ? Generating code is what makes this compilicated. Why do you think using a different tool will make it more complex?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Hello, I have added the requirements after the question

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Your suggestion is great, but I hope we can focus our discussion on how to implement this requirement through preprocessing methods, or is it possible?

Comment: You won't get a straight answer if someone has the suspicion that this is an "XY Problem". ;) That said, we had the same goal some years ago, just that we used an interface definition file from which we rendered stubs, declarations, linker scripts etc using a custom made tool. I'm not aware of any "proper" tools, though COM/CORBA seem to go into the right direction. Another alternative would be OpenAPI or gRPC, though that's rather a networked interface thing.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt sometimes environment doesn't permit use of some advance tools.  But it loked to methat could be ither CTRP generation issue, or some automated interface generation or for shared libraries.  The last one rarely uses _just_ one macro for them all, any solution would be fragile.

Comment: Are you asking how to use macros to implement the pimpl pattern for you? If so don't just do the typing or make a code generator.

Comment: that looks like wrong use of PIMPL unless the sole purpose of PIMPL is binary compatibility with shared library and not hiding complex private functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your arguments are trivially copyable (which stuff crossing a DLL boundary should be), you can use this:

```cpp
#define FOR_EACH_FUNC(_) \
    _(int, add, int(a), int(b)) \
    _(int, subtract, int(a), int(b))
```

Which will just be a bracketed name in the function declaration but be a functional cast as an expression.

This won't work with multi-word type names like `unsigned long long`, but you can use a typedef (`using ull = unsigned long long;`) or `std::type_identity_t<unsigned long long>`.

---

If you don't mind automatically named parameters (`int _0, int _1`), you can do this with [Boost.Preprocessor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html):

```cpp
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/comma_if.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repeat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_i.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/size.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/to_seq.hpp>

#define NUMBERED_ARGUMENTS_DECL_IMPL(R, PREFIX, I, TYPE) BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(I) TYPE BOOST_PP_CAT(PREFIX, I)
#define NUMBERED_ARGUMENTS_DECL(...) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(NUMBERED_ARGUMENTS_DECL_IMPL, _, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))
// `NUMBERED_ARGUMENTS_DECL(int, char, void*)` -> `int _0, char _1, void* _2`

#define NUMBERED_ARGUMENTS_EXPR_IMPL(Z, I, PREFIX) BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(I) BOOST_PP_CAT(PREFIX, I)
#define NUMBERED_ARGUMENTS_EXPR(...) BOOST_PP_REPEAT(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__), NUMBERED_ARGUMENTS_EXPR_IMPL, _)
// `NUMBERED_ARGUMENTS_DECL(int, char, void*)` -> `_0, _1, _2`

#define FOR_EACH_FUNC(_) \
    _(int, add, int, int) \
    _(int, subtract, int, int)

#define FORWARD_FUNC(ret, func, ...) \
    ret func(NUMBERED_ARGUMENTS_DECL(__VA_ARGS__)) { \
        return impl->func(NUMBERED_ARGUMENTS_EXPR(__VA_ARGS__)); \
    } \

FOR_EACH_FUNC(FORWARD_FUNC)
```

Comment: The parent solution may accidently suffer from MVP. +1 for boost solution, but that might be another dependency.

Comment: Thank you very much. The Boost solution is great and very useful to me. Although some dependencies have been added, the boot processor related libraries are only header files.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor lacks some functionality In general this would require a code generator, if you want a self-documenting code, i.e. consumer can read code in order to figure out how to use it.

The only way doing this in code requires a variadic template. I used for a prototyping an interface for Protobuf a limited case, where a function is a member of class template and it passes arguments as a whole pack:

```
template <class T>
struct UniversalBufTraits;

// There were some other declarations 


// Declares const and non-const version
// There might be overloaded versions of FuncName
#define DECLARE_METHOD(MethodName, ClassType, FuncName)     \
 template<class ClassType, typename ...Args>                \
        auto MethodName(ClassType& impl, Args... args) -> decltype(impl.FuncName(args...)) \
        { return impl.FuncName(args...); } \
 template<class ClassType, typename ...Args>                \
        auto MethodName(const ClassType& impl, Args... args) const -> decltype(impl.FuncName(args...)) \
        { return impl.FuncName(args...); }
  
template <>
struct UniversalBufTraits<ImplClass> {
    // bridge
    DECLARE_METHOD(tableSize, ImplClass, table_size);
    DECLARE_METHOD(getTable, ImplClass, table);
    DECLARE_METHOD(muTable, ImplClass, mutable_table);
    DECLARE_METHOD(addTableItem, ImplClass, add_table);
};
```

now these functions were used internally and not exposed to end user. The 'impl' is a private class of Bridge pattern which used this as an interface. It looks simpler if we call local member function:

```
// Declares const and non-const version of local  member function
#define DECLARE_MY_METHOD(MethodName, FuncName)     \
     template<typename ...Args>             \
            auto MethodName(Args... args) -> decltype(this->FuncName(args...)) \
            { return this->FuncName(args...); } \
     template<typename ...Args>             \
            auto MethodName(Args... args) const -> decltype(this->FuncName(args...)) \
            { return this->FuncName(args...); }


template <>
struct UniversalInterface<ImplClass> : protected ImplClass {
    // bridge
    DECLARE_MY_METHOD(tableSize,    table_size);
    DECLARE_MY_METHOD(getTable,     table);
    DECLARE_MY_METHOD(muTable,      mutable_table);
    DECLARE_MY_METHOD(addTableItem, add_table);
};
```

That suspiciosly looks like a CRTP.

For loading functions from shared library or DLL you already have function types (for pointers). You can use a function type as a declaration of function, which can be used in macrodefinitions:

```
using FooFuncType = void (int, float); 

FooFuncType   *foo;   // this is a pointer to a loaded function

FooFuncType   myFoo;  // this is a declaration of function with same signature as `foo`!

struct ClassA {
   FooFuncType  foo;  // method with same signature. 
};
```

That's all what might be exposed to consumer. Some widely used libraries and API exploit is, altohough it doesn't make themsafe (e.g. OpenGL). For code in .cpp a separate definition is used.